# Uncaught ReferenceError: ReactDOMServer is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, jsx, react-dom-server

Hello everyone I work on a Java Web project using react and jquery to render dynamic web pages. So I wanted to use the function ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup (element) to retrieve the html nodes related to the html element but I receive as an error:

```
***Uncaught ReferenceError: ReactDOMServer is not defined***
```

I also searched the net to find cdn ReactDOMServer to correct the error but other errors occur.
Here is a sample code:

**HTML FILE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>ORION WAMBERT</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body{
                font-family: "comic sans ms";
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>   
        <script type="text/javascript" src="react.development.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="react-dom.development.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="babel.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script type="text/babel" src="appReact.jsx">
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**JSX FILE**

```
class Button extends React.Component{
    handleClick(e){
        ReactDOM.render(<TextView text="HELLO WORLD"/>,$("#root").get(0));
    }
    render(){
        return <button onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.props.value}</button>;
    }
}

class TextView extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return <h3>{this.text}</h3>;
    }
}
let element=<Button value="click me"/>;
$("#root").html(ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(element));
```

Comment: import ReactDOMServer as `var ReactDOMServer = require('react-dom/server');`

Comment: I added this line in my code but unfortunately it always gives the same error:  `appReact.jsx:16 Uncaught ReferenceError: ReactDOMServer is not defined
    at <anonymous>:63:17
    at i (babel.min.js:24)
    at r (babel.min.js:24)
    at e.src.n.(anonymous function).l.content (http://localhost:100/cao/babel.min.js:24:30503)
    at XMLHttpRequest.n.onreadystatechange (babel.min.js:24)`

Answer (score 0):

the problem was resolved : [github link](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13262#event-1750912505)